# Retrieve Xml output from Sql Server 2005

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, resultset

Hi could someone provide me some clues or solution to retrieve record sets like below

Note: I read the MSDN documentation but leads me nowhere but hair loss :(

Just for the assumption think I have 2 tables connected via `Rid` field

**Table 1 fields,**

```
Rid,UserName,Hash
```

**Table2 fields**

```
Rid,Phone,City,Email
```

`table1` and `table2` are connected via the Rid field.

I would like to have a xml output using xml auto, or xml explicit or which ever xml operations you got in SQL Server Express 2005.

Output expected:

```
<UserDetails>
    <Account>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Hash></Hash>
    </Account>
    <Personal>
        <Phone1></Phone1>
        <City1></City1>
        <Phone2></Phone2>
        <City2></City2>
    </Personal>
</UserDetails>
```

The personal details can have n records. But account details are only one.

Comment: So do you pass in a `Rid` into a procedure to get this output for a single user, or do you want a single XML for all users??

Comment: @marc_s I would like it to work both the ways. I would pass in rid for retriving single record. Leave it empty in case i wanted everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this - what I cannot do is create those "embedded enumerations"

```
<Phone1></Phone1>
<City1></City1>
<Phone2></Phone2>
<City2></City2>
```

I don't know of any way to easily make those sequentially numbered XML tags ...

All I can do is the output I'm going to show at the end:

```
SELECT
    t1.UserName AS 'Account/UserName',
    t1.UserHash AS 'Account/Hash',
    (SELECT
        t2.Phone AS 'Phone',
        t2.City AS 'City'
     FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t2.Rid = t1.Rid
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS 'Personal'
FROM
    table1 t1
FOR XML PATH('UserDetails'), ROOT('Users')
```

This gives me an output something like:

```
<Users>
  <UserDetails>
    <Account>
      <UserName>xxxxx</UserName>
      <Hash>hhhhhhh</Hash>
    </Account>
    <Personal>
      <Phone>.....</Phone>
      <City>.....</City>
      <Phone>..........</Phone>
      <City>.........</City>
    </Personal>
  </UserDetails>
  <UserDetails>
    <Account>
      <UserName>cccccccccccc</UserName>
      <Hash>hhhhhhhhhhhh</Hash>
    </Account>
    <Personal>
      <Phone>................</Phone>
      <City>...........</City>
    </Personal>
  </UserDetails>
</Users>
```

Of course, if you want, you can add a `WHERE t1.rid = xxx` condition to your outer `SELECT` in order to limit the user and its details retrieved.

Comment: thanks for the superb code. Works like charm and does the job. I will shoot another stack to check if this is a optimal method on DBStackExchage. Thanks